# Proving that the set $E=\left\{\frac{xy}{x^{2} +3y} ;x >0;y >0\right\}$ does not have an upper bound

Tags: real-numbers

It has been 2 days that i am trying to prove that the set E defined by
$$E=\left\{\frac{xy}{x^{2} +3y} ;x >0;y >0\right\}$$
`doesn't have a upper bound,but without success
I first supposed that E has a upper bound M and i tried to find x and y (depending on M) such that the expression obtained will be superior to M but this method seem a bit hazardous to me and i still don't have found the appropriate x and y.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Along the path $y=x^2$ the function becomes $$f(x,x^2) = \frac{x}{4}$$

Comment: Ninad Munshi's suggestion is a good one and can be generalized: if you're trying to prove a multivariate function doesn't have some property, try and homogenize the degree.

Answer (score 2):

Set $x=\sqrt{y}$. The expression then becomes

$$\frac{xy}{x^{2} +3y}=\frac{y^{3/2}}{y +3y}=\frac{y^{3/2}}{4y}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{y}$$

Since this is unbounded we are done.

Comment: Please read here for information on formatting MathJax                
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference